# List nearby/discoverable bluetooth devices, including already paired, in Python, on Linux

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth

I'm trying to list all nearby/discoverable bluetooth devices, *including those already paired*, using Python on Linux.

I know how to list services for a device using its address, and can connect successfully:

```
services = bluetooth.find_service(address='...')
```

Reading the PyBluez docs I would expect any nearby device to show up if I don't specify any criteria:

> "If no criteria are specified, then returns a list of all nearby services detected."

The "only" thing I need right now is to be able to list already paired devices, whether they are on, off, nearby or not. Much like the list I'm getting in All Settings --> Bluetooth in Ubuntu/Unity.

Btw, the following *does not* list already paired devices on my machine, even if they are on/nearby. Probably because they are not discoverable once paired:

```
import bluetooth
for d in bluetooth.discover_devices(flush_cache=True):
    print d
```

Any ideas ...?

**Edit:** I found and installed "bluez-tools".

```
bt-device --list
```

... gives me the information I need, i.e. addresses of added devices.

I've checked the C source, found out that this might not be as easy as I thought it would be.

Still don't know how to do this in Python ...

**Edit:** I think DBUS might be what I should be reading up on. Seems complicated enough. If anyone has got some code to share I would be really happy. :)

Comment: You may be able to find the answer you're looking for by searching through the Blueman Project's [source code](http://blueman-project.org/downloads.html).

Comment: @Richard, I thought about it also, and started doing it, but it is really wrapping around `dbus`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the adoption of the version 5 of the Bluetooth API most of the functions used in the @Micke solutions were dropped and the interaction
with the bus take place throught the ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects [1]

```
import dbus


def proxyobj(bus, path, interface):
    """ commodity to apply an interface to a proxy object """
    obj = bus.get_object('org.bluez', path)
    return dbus.Interface(obj, interface)


def filter_by_interface(objects, interface_name):
    """ filters the objects based on their support
        for the specified interface """
    result = []
    for path in objects.keys():
        interfaces = objects[path]
        for interface in interfaces.keys():
            if interface == interface_name:
                result.append(path)
    return result


bus = dbus.SystemBus()

# we need a dbus object manager
manager = proxyobj(bus, "/", "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")
objects = manager.GetManagedObjects()

# once we get the objects we have to pick the bluetooth devices.
# They support the org.bluez.Device1 interface
devices = filter_by_interface(objects, "org.bluez.Device1")

# now we are ready to get the informations we need
bt_devices = []
for device in devices:
    obj = proxyobj(bus, device, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
    bt_devices.append({
        "name": str(obj.Get("org.bluez.Device1", "Name")),
        "addr": str(obj.Get("org.bluez.Device1", "Address"))
    })
```

In the `bt_device` list there are dictionaries with the desired data:
ie

for example

```
[{
    'name': 'BBC micro:bit [zigiz]', 
    'addr': 'E0:7C:62:5A:B1:8C'
 }, {
    'name': 'BBC micro:bit [putup]',
    'addr': 'FC:CC:69:48:5B:32'
}]
```

Reference:
[1] http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/

Answer (score 9):

I managed to solve the problem myself. The following snippet lists addresses for all paired devices, on my default bluetooth adapter:

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()

manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('org.bluez', '/'), 'org.bluez.Manager')

adapterPath = manager.DefaultAdapter()

adapter = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('org.bluez', adapterPath), 'org.bluez.Adapter')

for devicePath in adapter.ListDevices():
    device = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('org.bluez', devicePath),'org.bluez.Device')
    deviceProperties = device.GetProperties()
    print deviceProperties["Address"]
```

Comment: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "DefaultAdapter" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist

Comment: @WolfgangFahl Since the adoption of the bluez 5 API the support for custom inquiry of bluetooth device was dropped. You have to revert to bluez 4 or use the alternate version I posted

Answer (score 5):

You could always execute it as a shell command and read what it returns:

```
import subprocess as sp
p = sp.Popen(["bt-device", "--list"], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, close_fds=True)
(stdout, stdin) = (p.stdout, p.stdin)
data = stdout.readlines()
```

Now `data` will include a list of all output lines which you can format and play with as you like.

Comment: Thank you! That would have been my fall-back solution if I hadn't managed to do the whole thing in Python.

Answer (score 2):

a bit long but does the trick in one line

```
bt-device -l | egrep '\(.*\)' | grep -oP '(?<=\()[^\)]+' | xargs -n1 bt-device -i
```

Comment: for anyone here like me, this requires first `sudo apt install bluez-tools bluez` if not performed yet